# How do I setup Zcash in my private network?

Tags: blockchain, zcash

I've just started to get into Zcash and I've setup a Zcash node in my local by following this [user guide](https://zcash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rtd_pages/user_guide.html).
Currently I'm pointing to the test network according to the conf file :

```
//Zcash.conf
testnet=1
addnode=testnet.z.cash
gen=1
genproclimit=-1
```

Now I need to setup this on my local machine, i.e I want to run my own network. Any idea or links available that would help me do this?

Also the test network has been broken recently,

testnet has been broken recently -> https://github.com/zcash/zcash/issues/3552

A fix is pending merge -> https://github.com/zcash/zcash/pull/3559

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `regtest` mode. You'll find examples in Bitcoin e.g. https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#regtest-mode which are essentially the same as for zcashd. So startup with `zcashd -regtest`.